# Rewrite rules and maintain URL

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

I have `archive-jobs.php` which lists all jobs on the following URL; website.com/jobs

What I want to do is add a rewrite rule so if you were to go to:-

`website.com/jobs/finance`

or

`website.com/jobs/finance/nottinghamshire`

It would keep the URL as it is but it will load the `archive-jobs.php` file (essentially it will loads /jobs/ but the URL wouldn't change if you were to go to any of the links above).

Also, if there is a third directory, i.e:-

`website.com/jobs/finance/nottinghamshire/finance-support-director`

I wouldn't want it to load the `archive-jobs.php` file.

So essentially I would only want it to load `/jobs/` if at has less than 3 parameters after `/jobs/` if that makes sense.

Is this possible to do by adding a rewrite rule or via htaccess?

Comment: What would the main query contain on those pages?

Comment: @Milo - At the moment it is just using a standard WP_Query, and you would get to this page by using the search form on the homepage which uses POST action.

Comment: Searching for what? The main query has to load *something* on those pages, otherwise they will 404.

Comment: @Milo - I have a custom post type called 'Jobs', and then I am using ACF to populate the fields for Jobs, the archive-jobs.php just shows all the jobs, and the form on the homepage just posts the selected values to archive-jobs.php to filter which jobs to display.

Comment: The issue is that using POST, the url would always be website.com/jobs, where as I need it to display website.com/<job sector>/<job location>/ for SEO purposes